# Anime with female main character who dies trying to kill dragons again and again and is resurrected with new powers

Tags: story-identification, anime

An anime where a town is under the rule of despotic dragons. A girl decides to fight them, she gets killed and comes back with a new super power every time till she defeats all of them. Really old anime; 1970's I think.

One of the powers she had was moving on balls that were under her feet. Another scene was where she was skipping with a dead dragon's spinal cord.

Comment: You have a nice start here but can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/58193) and see if there is anything else you can [edit] in?

Comment: can you add more details? Like, how does the girl look, are there any friends or team with her, where did you watch it, what is the style etc.

Comment: I don't have anything besides this information